# Why Spark cannot run on Android System?

Tags: android, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I saw the April fool article, it seems that spark cannot run on Android devices.

I'm confused about why the Apache spark cannot run on the mobile device.

It can run on RaspberryPi, so it supports ARM CPU.
It can run on Linux, Mac OS, and any Unix-like system, but Android is a system that based on Unix.
It needs Java to run. Maybe there are differences between JVM and DVM, but I cannot understand what caused the problem. They all support Java 1.8

I try to add spark and spark streaming in the android studio, but it just stuck at building time (DEXBuilderForDebug)and don't have any progress.
Spark is an open source, I want to figure out that it can be modified to support Android or not?

Thanks for any advise.